# Subsonic 3 + SQLite 3

Tags: subsonic, sqlite, subsonic3

I am trying to use Subsonic for SQLite. I got an exception "SQLite error near ".": syntax error".

VS 2008; Subsonic 3.0.0.3; SQLite 3.

How I can to resolve it?

Also, cananybody provide an project example with Subsonic for SQLite included.

Comment: teaching to fish--> get the sql that is causing the problem and 1) see if you can suss out the issue AND 2) include the sql with your question. 

Otherwise you are just asking too much with too little and will get minimal to no response.

HTH